# Why "The 'empty' method should be used to check for emptiness instead of 'size" by clang-tidy?

Tags: c++, containers, std, stdvector, clang-tidy

When performing the check:

```
std::string st = "hello";
bool is_empty = st.size() > 0;
```

I get the Clang-Tidy warning mentioned above.

Why is it better to use the `empty()` method instead?

Comment: In my opinion it is not always better to use  `empty()` for this. The code will sometimes be harder to read. Consider `if (foo.size() && bar.size() && blarg.size())` as compared to `if (!foo.empty() && !bar.empty() && !blarg.empty())`. The semantics of "if this and this and this has a size" is easier on my brain than "If this is not empty and this is not empty and this is not empty". But I suppose that this boils down to what you are used to. And in C++11 the time complexity of `empty()` and `size()` are both constant.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Clang documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/readability-container-size-empty.html)

> **readability-container-size-empty**
>
> Checks whether a call to the size() method can be replaced with a call
> to empty().
>
> The emptiness of a container should be checked using the empty()
> method instead of the size() method. It is not guaranteed that size()
> is a constant-time function, and it is generally more efficient and
> also shows clearer intent to use empty(). Furthermore some containers
> may implement the empty() method but not implement the size() method.
> Using empty() whenever possible makes it easier to switch to another
> container in the future.

`std::forward_list` is and example to a container that doesn't have `size()` method as seen here : [do-all-containers-have-a-size-function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27881869/do-all-containers-have-a-size-function)

After C++11 time complexity of `size()` is **constant** according to its standard by [isocpp](https://isocpp.org/blog/2017/05/quick-q-is-listsize-really-on)

Comment: Generally agree, but it may be preferable to use explicit `size` in unit tests since it might lead to better error messages. For example, `CHECK(result.size() == 0)` might produce a failure message such as `CHECK failed: 5 == 0`.

Comment: Link is dead :\